# What are the territorial scopes of sections 4-5 of the Public Order Act 1986?

Tags: united-kingdom, england-and-wales, jurisdiction, scotland, public-order

Sections 4, 4A & 5, Public Order Act 1986 contain offences, do they apply only to England and Wales, or do they also apply to Scotland or Northern Ireland?

Comment: I don't understand the close-vote. In what way does the question lack clarity or need more details? It seems very clear to me, and it's a useful question which has generated a useful answer for people who don't know how to check geographical extent in an Act.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sections 4, 4A & 5 are applicable only to England & Wales.

You can see this if you click "[Show Geographical Extent](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1986/64?view=extent):"

[image]

That information is drawn from [s. 42 (Extent)](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1986/64/section/42).